# Telerik Scheduler - drag and drop

Tags: telerik-scheduler

I use Telerik demo scheduler as my base, as it seen in http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/scheduler/uniqueid-property-how-to-access-it.aspx
So i have implemented data loading from SQL to this scheduler. Now I want to implement drag and drop. So, how can I get my appointment values in old place and values in new place on scheduler and what the best technique to do that? I would use these values, to implement  update of appointment dates in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        private void OnAppointmentEdited(object sender, AppointmentEditedEventArgs e)
        {

            Appointment eAppo = e.Appointment as Appointment;
            SessionAppointment ses = e.Appointment as SessionAppointment;

            if(eAppo != null && ses != null)
            {
                DateTime dateStart = eAppo.Start; //new datestart
                DateTime dateEnd = eAppo.End;//new dateend
                string id = ses.UniqueId;//id

}
}
```